# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a tensorflow custom layer that I want to use with functional API for training. But I get a weird error that I don't know how to fix. Here is the code:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def scaled_dot_product_attention(query, key, value, mask=None):
  key_dim = tf.cast(tf.shape(key)[-1], tf.float32)
  scaled_scores = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True) / np.sqrt(key_dim)

  if mask is not None:
    scaled_scores = tf.where(mask==0, -np.inf, scaled_scores)

  softmax = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
  weights = softmax(scaled_scores) 
  return tf.matmul(weights, value), weights

class MultiHeadSelfAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
    super(MultiHeadSelfAttention, self).__init__()
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.num_heads = num_heads

    self.d_head = self.d_model // self.num_heads

    self.wq = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)
    self.wk = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)
    self.wv = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)

    # Linear layer to generate the final output.
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)
  
  def split_heads(self, x):

    split_inputs = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.num_heads, self.d_head))
    return tf.transpose(split_inputs, perm=[1,0,2])
  
  def merge_heads(self, x):
    
    merged_inputs = tf.transpose(x, perm=[1,0,2])
    return tf.reshape(merged_inputs, (-1, self.d_model))

  def call(self, q, k, v, mask):
    qs = self.wq(q)
    ks = self.wk(k)
    vs = self.wv(v)

    qs = self.split_heads(qs)
    ks = self.split_heads(ks)
    vs = self.split_heads(vs)

    output, attn_weights = scaled_dot_product_attention(qs, ks, vs, mask)
    output = self.merge_heads(output)

    return self.dense(output) 

# -------- Model Building -----------
values = Input(shape=(3,12))
values_emb = MultiHeadSelfAttention(12, 3)(values,values,values, mask = None)
model = Model(values, values_emb)
model.summary()
```

The `MultiHeadSelfAttention` class successfully works if you give it a random input and it generates an output. But it throws an error when you want to put it in a model. The error is:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (multi_head_self_attention_4/Cast:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Change this line `scaled_scores = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True) / np.sqrt(key_dim)`  to `scaled_scores = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True) / tf.math.sqrt(key_dim)`

Comment: @I'mahdi Thanks that fixed the problem. Couldn't find that numpy bit sneaking in.